# How to find the full path to a python module's included DLL file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, cygwin

I'm trying to programmatically determine the path to the included/installed DLL file for a particular package. I've read countless SO pages, but cannot find any solution. Perhaps I've missed something and it's not possible?

The package is [capstone](https://github.com/aquynh/capstone) and was manually installed from sources with the python3 bindings on Windows via *Cygwin*. Everything works.

```sh
# python3 -c "import os,inspect,capstone; print(os.path.dirname(inspect.getfile(capstone)))"
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/capstone-4.0.0rc1-py3.6.egg/capstone

# python3 -c "import capstone; print(capstone._lib)"
capstone.dll
```

1. The path shown above is to the `*.egg` file, but that path doesn't actually exist,
   unless you unzip the file.
2. Within the EGG file, the location is in `./*.egg/capstone/lib/capstone.dll`
3. But in the OS, the real system location of `capstone.dll` is in:
   **`/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/capstone/lib`**

---

How can I get the true path (3) in Python3?

---

**EDIT:**

Perhaps [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/) could be useful? But I've come up with this ugly thing, that could easily break, so hoping for a more *pythonic* way.

```
# python3 -c "import capstone; print('DLL path: %s' % capstone._path_list[4] + '/' + capstone.__name__ + '/lib/' + capstone._lib)"
DLL path: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/capstone/lib/capstone.dll
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding the `python` tag for more feedback.  Maybe also `windows`

Comment: Have you tried `python3 -c "import capstone; print(capstone.__file__)"`?

Comment: How exactly did you *install* the package? Egg installs are sort of all but deprecated in the Python packaging community, but nevertheless are still (unfortunately) what you get if you manually run `python setup.py install` of projects that use setuptools. Instead of running the `setup.py` directly, run `pip install .` in the source directory. Pip will install the package in a "flat" installation that is generally easier to deal with. That said, as @YiFei points out, to get the path to any module `import foo; foo.__file__` should give you the path to the module.

Comment: @Iguananaut Unfortunately, that package is outdated and need to be compiled and installed semi-manually via make and a shell script. So the `__file__` thing doesn't provide the *.dll file path.

Comment: The existence of `__file__` has nothing to do with build process, and is a normal feature of Python modules. Is the DLL in question a compiled Python module, or just some external library? If it's the latter then there is no standard way to find its path; that would be somewhat specific to the project depending on how it's used. However, if the DLL is installed inside the Python package, then you would get the path of the relevant (sub-)package from its `__file__` attribute, and join the DLL filename to that.

Comment: I see now that capstone is a larger project with Python bindings. It still uses the standard build tools for Python packages, and the Makefile it includes for installing the Python bindings is just doing so in a slightly outdated manner, which could and should be fixed.

Comment: I should add that there was also some issue with the build/install script building the DLL with the wrong name, as `capstone.` and not `capstone.dll`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've "installed" *Capstone* by copying:

1. *Python* bindings *dir* ([[GitHub]: capstone-engine/capstone - (master) capstone/bindings/python/capstone](https://github.com/capstone-engine/capstone/tree/master/bindings/python/capstone)) in my *CWD*
2. *capstone.dll* from the binaries *.zip* file, in the *dir* from ***#1.***

While starting to prepare an elaborate (and general) example, I browsed a bit the source (as at the beginning, it didn't find the *.dll* - hence the need for setting *${LIBCAPSTONE_PATH}*), and noticed that the *.dll* path is stored in *capstone._path* :)

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/cygdrive/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q052946558]> ~/sopr.sh
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> capstone  capstone-4.0-win64.zip  capstone-master.zip
> [064bit prompt]> ls capstone
> __init__.py   __pycache__  arm_const.py  arm64_const.py  evm.py        m680x.py        m68k.py        mips.py        ppc.py        sparc.py        systemz.py     tms320c64x.py        x86.py        xcore.py
> __init__.pyc  arm.py       arm64.py      capstone.dll    evm_const.py  m680x_const.py  m68k_const.py  mips_const.py  ppc_const.py  sparc_const.py  sysz_const.py  tms320c64x_const.py  x86_const.py  xcore_const.py
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> python3
> Python 3.6.4 (default, Jan  7 2018, 15:53:53)
> [GCC 6.4.0] on cygwin
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> >>> import capstone
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "/cygdrive/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q052946558/capstone/__init__.py", line 315, in <module>
>     raise ImportError("ERROR: fail to load the dynamic library.")
> ImportError: ERROR: fail to load the dynamic library.
> >>>
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> LIBCAPSTONE_PATH=$(pwd)/capstone python3
> Python 3.6.4 (default, Jan  7 2018, 15:53:53)
> [GCC 6.4.0] on cygwin
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> >>> import capstone
> >>> import os
> >>> os.path.join(capstone._path, capstone._lib)
> '/cygdrive/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q052946558/capstone/capstone.dll'
> ```